# Chlorinated hydrocarbon destruction

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, organic-reduction, organic-oxidation

What's a convenient method for lab-scale destruction of chlorinated hydrocarbons?

Reductive dechlorination, total oxidation are fine as well as other routes you want to point out. If specific chlorocarbons are needed, consider 100ml of dichloromethane or tetrachloroethylene. Ideal end products would be $\ce{H_2O}$, $\ce{CO_2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$; formic acid and other organic compounds are fine as long as they are not chlorinated.

So far I've been looking at oxidative species such as $\ce{O_3}$, $\ce{OH^{.}}$ or $\ce{SO_4^{.-}}$ via Fenton's reaction, UV/ozone, UV/$\ce{TiO_2}$, Persulfates. Would $\ce{H_2SO_5}$ oxidize effectively?

I am open to completely different routes. Reference to papers are much appreciated.